# Angular giving same $$hashKey for two different objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am not able to understand why is angular these two objects as same here are the results of console log

```
$$hashKey: "object:794"
id: "51276798"
title: "abc"

$$hashKey: "object:794"
id: "123579898"
title: "def"
```

How can I overcome this I don't want to use track by **$index**

Comment: can you show the code that is causing this to occur?